# Is the starred version of \ccref really necessary?

Tags: cross-referencing, languages, package-writing, crefthe

**UPDATE:** New syntax has been adopted, and the package `ccref` has been renamed into `crefthe`. The `\crefthe` now decides whether to pass the preposition to all definite articles depending on current language, and if the automatic result is not OK, there are also two manual versions `\crefthe-` and `\crefthe+`. The starred version has been reserved for "no hyperlink" version, as @gusbrs kindly reminded in his comment.

---

The `cleveref` package provides wonderful cross referencing features and it is very convenient to use it. However, for languages like French, Italian, Spanish, etc., there would be some difficulty for `\cref` to handle the definite articles (especially when it comes to article contractions). Usually one would have to consider switching to manually referencing in such cases, but that would cause extra effort in some cases like when the referencing names should have specific fonts or colors.

To improve the situation a little bit, I wrote a new package named [ccref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/crefthe) (which is available on CTAN by now), which provides a wrapped version `\ccref` of `\cref` for handling definite articles (and especially for the contraction of prepositions and articles). For the moment, there are two versions of `\ccref`:

1. `\ccref[<prep>]{<labels>}`

   - the normal form, which pass the preposition `<prep>` to the first definite article in the referencing string
2. `\ccref*[<prep>]{<labels>}`

   - the starred form, which pass the preposition `<prep>` to every definite article in the referencing string

Originally, the reason for having these two versions is because that in French one usually needs to repeat the preposition several times, while in Spanish the preposition is only needed at the beginning.

However, now that I think about this, is the starred version really necessary? That said, if the language is fixed, would there be any possibility that both forms of `\ccref` shall be used in order to get the correct result? To my experience, in French I've always been using the starred form, and a classmate told me that the normal form would be suffice for Spanish. But I'm not sure about the other languages, and here I sincerely ask for your suggestions.

If it turns out that each language corresponds to exactly one form, then in the next version I shall remove the starred version and adopt an auto-detection mechanism.

Comment: I think that the claim that "for language[s] like French, Italian, Spanish, etc., `\cref` is not able to handle the definite articles properly" verges on being misleading. First, `\cref` and friends don't insert definite (or indirect) articles *at all* -- and the `cleveref` package has never claimed otherwise. Second, the absence of definite articles doesn't apply to (just) romance languages such French, Italian, and Spanish. Instead, it applies to *all languages* since, by its very design, `cleveref` doesn't provide definite articles at all, to *any* language.

Comment: @Mico You are absolutely right. Actually when writing these sentences I was thinking of article contractions, but later it turns out that contraction is not the only problem to handle. Anyway, please forgive my misleading expression.

Comment: Thanks. I think the main contribution of your package is to provide an extra convenience -- the insertion of appropriate definite articles. That's really neat, and it may attract some attention in its own right. There's no need, though, to create the impression that the package somehow fixes a so-far-unaddressed bug or shortcoming in the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Jinwen and @Mico you may be interested in https://github.com/frougon/xcref and https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever.

Comment: Jinwen, cool package, thanks! Commenting on your question, and despite the issue of the distinction you are trying to make there between the starred and the regular version. But, in cross-referencing packages, very commonly, the starred version is used to denote the "no hyperlink" version of the command. So, if you use it for this purpose, you'd loose this quite traditional idiom.

Comment: @gusbrs Thank you for your links and comments! I must say I learnt from the links that German is much much complicated than I thought it would be, and `xcref` does a much better job than my little package could. It is such a pity that it hasn't been added as part of the TeX distribution. Regarding the "traditional idiom", depending on the answer to this question, I will decide whether to add another command to do the job of the currently starred one, and reserve the starred one for the "no hyperlink" version. Also, looking forward to see your `zref-clever` on CTAN.

Comment: Jinwen, this is complicated an issue indeed. I did like your minimalist approach, but yeah, it may reach some limitations depending on the language and what people want. The question is always the right "balance". And, I'm not sure your question will be given an answer, first it is really difficult to answer in general, second it is less a LaTeX question than a "linguistic" one. But I'll share the comment I received from Alan Munn, who is a linguist, when I asked for comments about declension: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59418194#59418194. There you have it. :)